# Invalid default value when trying to modify a different column

Tags: mysql, linux

**Problem**: I'm trying to modify my column's datatype from a smaller VARCHAR to a larger one so that I can take in IPv6 addresses as well (my current column only takes a size large enough for IPv4 addresses)

**Example**:
`ALTER TABLE accounts MODIFY COLUMN ip VARCHAR(45)`

shoots back an error as

```
Invalid default value for 'birthday'
```

I'm a bit confused because while I do have a birthday column in my accounts table, why is an error being thrown here about it when I'm not touching it?

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE accounts
```

[image]

Comment: Anyone can help me out?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  I don't know what is happening, but maybe that will give a clue.  Also what version are you running?  And has this table been migrated from an older version?  If so, what was the first such version?

Comment: @RickJames I updated the post with SHOW CREATE TABLES. I'll take a look at the MySQL version next.

Answer (score 1):

What versions?  There have been several changes, some incompatible, regarding `DATE` and other temporal types.  This one jumps out:

> ----- 2013-09-21 5.7.2 Milestone 12 & 2013-07-31 5.6.13 -- Bugs Fixed -- Incompatible Change -----
>
> It is possible for a column DEFAULT value to be valid for the sql_mode
>   (
>   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sql_mode
>   ) value at table-creation time but invalid for the sql_mode (
>   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sql_mode
>   ) value when rows are inserted or updated. Example:
>
> SET sql_mode = ''; CREATE TABLE t (d DATE DEFAULT 0); SET sql_mode =
>   'NO_ZERO_DATE,STRICT_ALL_TABLES'; INSERT INTO t (d) VALUES(DEFAULT);
>
> In this case, 0 should be accepted for the CREATE TABLE (
>   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html ) but
>   rejected for the INSERT (
>   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html ). However, the
>   server did not evaluate DEFAULT values used for inserts or updates
>   against the current sql_mode. In the example, the INSERT (
>   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html ) succeeds and
>   inserts '0000-00-00' into the DATE (
>   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html ) column.
>
> The server now applies the proper sql_mode (
>   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sql_mode
>   ) checks to generate a warning or error at insert or update time.
>
> A resulting incompatibility for replication if you use statement-based
>   logging (binlog_format=STATEMENT (
>   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#sysvar_binlog_format
>   )) is that if a slave is upgraded, a nonupgraded master will execute
>   the preceding example without error, whereas the INSERT (
>   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html ) will fail on the
>   slave and replication will stop.
>
> To deal with this, stop all new statements on the master and wait
>   until the slaves catch up. Then upgrade the slaves followed by the
>   master. Alternatively, if you cannot stop new statements, temporarily
>   change to row-based logging on the master (binlog_format=ROW (
>   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#sysvar_binlog_format
>   )) and wait until all slaves have processed all binary logs produced
>   up to the point of this change. Then upgrade the slaves followed by
>   the master and change the master back to statement-based logging.
>   (Bug #68041, Bug #16078943)

Comment: my sql version is: Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.13, for Linux (x86_64)

Comment: But what version did that `CREATE TABLE` come from?